# Find element for Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am just starting to learn `Selenium WebDriver`. I would like to find This checkbox and click. I can't get it on the straight because it is hidden. Should I get all checkboxes and after it get necessary field?

My code

[image]

`HTML`

[image]

Comment: Share your code and `HTML` as text, not as images. Also add exception log if you got any

Comment: `bodies` id is set to `div` did you want to select url inside that?

Comment: No i would like yo get all of the checkboxes. I think i should have to used `class="unstyle boxed bu-list-three-colums"`

Comment: Your code contains By.Name(bodystyle-4) and I can not see such element!

Comment: Sorry guys, i don't know what elements i should use, so i added test data to my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using XPATH as follows, to find the element highlighted in underline in the image attached in the question:

```
By.Xpath("//label[@for='bodystyle-5']")
```

note: `By.name` can be used ONLY for `name` attributes in HTML tags.

---

To find the HTML corresponding to a Web Element,

1. Right click on the element you want to find -> select `Inspect` option in Chrome (`Inspect Element` in Firefox).
2. If you want to evaluate XPath or CSS, Follow the steps:

   1. Open Firefox browser
   2. Install `Firebug` & `Firepath` plugins to Firefox
   3. Visit your application
   4. Right-click on the element that you want identify, and click on `Inspect Element with Firebug` option -> takes you to the elements HTML code.

You can try `Xpath` or `CSS selectors` in `Firepath` tab.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working.  CCan you explain me when should i use `for` to get all of the fields?

Comment: I used `@for='bodystyle-5'` because, HTML code contains `for` attribute. General syntax is `//tag[@attributeName=attributeValue]`. so, you can use any attribute in HTML like `name, value, id, class etc.`

Comment: but how can i get it not using the xPath?

Comment: 0other option is `CSS selectors`. apart from it, there is NO direct way to find. If you have any of `ID, name, class name, link text, tag name` then you can find directly using corresponding By. methods.